# create array tree from array list

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

i have a list like this:

```
array(
  array(id=>100, parentid=>0, name=>'a'),
  array(id=>101, parentid=>100, name=>'a'),
  array(id=>102, parentid=>101, name=>'a'),
  array(id=>103, parentid=>101, name=>'a'),
)
```

but way bigger so i need a efficient way to make this into a tree like structure like this:

```
array(
  id=>100, parentid=>0, name=>'a', children=>array(
    id=>101, parentid=>100, name=>'a', children=>array(
      id=>102, parentid=>101, name=>'a',
      id=>103, parentid=>101, name=>'a',
    )
  )
)
```

i cannot use things like nested set or things like that becoas i can add left and right values in my database.
any ideas?

Comment: didn't get it... your list is a PHP array?

Comment: @andre OP is looking for an adjacency list. There is a number of duplicates for this.

Comment: The arrays you have demoed do not make sense because you have duplicate keys. Did you mean to have an array of arrays or are you showing the implied meaning based on the index value?

Comment: sry typo in array but it was indeed array of arrays edited it now

Comment: This flat array list is one of kinds of tree store in relational database and is named Adjacency list. There are another ways to store tree in RDBMS which are described in articles like this: https://bitworks.software/en/2017-10-20-storing-trees-in-rdbms.html

Answer (score 67, accepted):

oke this is how i solved it:

```
$arr = array(
  array('id'=>100, 'parentid'=>0, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>101, 'parentid'=>100, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>102, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>103, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
);

$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $a){
    $new[$a['parentid']][] = $a;
}
$tree = createTree($new, array($arr[0]));
print_r($tree);

function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
            $l['children'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    } 
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: This works well, just make sure that, if you have more than one item with parentid=0, to loop through all the items and check for parentid == 0. If that's true, then run createTree on that item and append it to your tree array. Otherwise, this routine only works for the first item where parentid=0

Comment: Found this solusion, helped a lot!

Comment: Question: Is the &$list required or can it also work with $list? I believe that's what PHP uses to pass by ref. Also, is recursion discouraged in PHP?

Comment: @JinIzzraeel If you want to pass non-objects by ref, you need the ampersand. Recursion is not discouraged in PHP.

Comment: man you saved me from pulling out my hair today. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 47):

small fix if you need more than 1 parentid[0] element :)

```
$arr = array(
  array('id'=>100, 'parentid'=>0, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>101, 'parentid'=>100, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>102, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>103, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
);

$new = array();
foreach ($arr as $a){
    $new[$a['parentid']][] = $a;
}
$tree = createTree($new, $new[0]); // changed
print_r($tree);

function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
            $l['children'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    } 
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Any ideas how to get this one working with any parentId on the lowest level ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942115/convert-flat-array-to-nested-parent-child-structure#comment15908756_11942115

Comment: what if we will have a loop here?

Answer (score 23):

One more rework of [Thunderstriker's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196879/3141596)  - all the logic in one function:

```
/**
 * @param array $flatList - a flat list of tree nodes; a node is an array with keys: id, parentID, name.
 */
function buildTree(array $flatList)
{
    $grouped = [];
    foreach ($flatList as $node){
        $grouped[$node['parentID']][] = $node;
    }

    $fnBuilder = function($siblings) use (&$fnBuilder, $grouped) {
        foreach ($siblings as $k => $sibling) {
            $id = $sibling['id'];
            if(isset($grouped[$id])) {
                $sibling['children'] = $fnBuilder($grouped[$id]);
            }
            $siblings[$k] = $sibling;
        }
        return $siblings;
    };

    return $fnBuilder($grouped[0]);
}

// Example:
$flat = [
    ['id' => 100, 'parentID' => 0, 'name' => 'root'],
    ['id' => 101, 'parentID' => 100, 'name' => 'ch-1'],
    ['id' => 102, 'parentID' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-1'],
    ['id' => 103, 'parentID' => 101, 'name' => 'ch-1-2'],
];

$tree = buildTree($flat, 'parentID', 'id');
echo json_encode($tree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Playground: https://www.tehplayground.com/Ap4uUuwHWl9eiJIx

Comment: I liked this example so I wrapped it in a class and made it available on github here; https://github.com/srayner/NavTree

Comment: How to add an element to this tree as a child of a particular parent?

Comment: @HappyCoder just add an element to the $flat, for example `['id'=>103, 'parentID'=>101, 'name'=>'a']` - it's a child of a `['id'=>101, 'parentID'=>100, 'name'=>'a']` element

Comment: Based on @Vasily 's answer, I made an "array of instances" tree builder: https://gist.github.com/seniorpreacher/64adfcf4844974b568bc84bf3056c05e

Comment: What is idKey? My ide keeps complaining about it

Comment: @Sithell, that was an extra unused variable, deleted it, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Here is my adaptation from [arthur's rework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332361/305189):

```php
/* Recursive branch extrusion */
function createBranch(&$parents, $children) {
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if (isset($parents[$child['id']])) {
            $child['children'] =
                $this->createBranch($parents, $parents[$child['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $child;
    } 
    return $tree;
}

/* Initialization */
function createTree($flat, $root = 0) {
    $parents = array();
    foreach ($flat as $a) {
        $parents[$a['parent']][] = $a;
    }
    return $this->createBranch($parents, $parents[$root]);
}
```

Use:

```php
$tree = createTree($flat);
```

Comment: It works perfectly with multiple root parents with id 0.

Answer (score 8):

I created an unusual ('while-based' instead of recursive) but **multidimensional** sorting function that walk the array until there aren't any orphans. Here the function:

```
function treeze( &$a, $parent_key, $children_key )
{
    $orphans = true; $i;
    while( $orphans )
    {
        $orphans = false;
        foreach( $a as $k=>$v )
        {
            // is there $a[$k] sons?
            $sons = false;
            foreach( $a as $x=>$y )
            if( isset($y[$parent_key]) and $y[$parent_key]!=false and $y[$parent_key]==$k )  
            { 
                $sons=true; 
                $orphans=true; 
                break;
            }

            // $a[$k] is a son, without children, so i can move it
            if( !$sons and isset($v[$parent_key]) and $v[$parent_key]!=false )
            {
                $a[$v[$parent_key]][$children_key][$k] = $v;
                unset( $a[$k] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Recommendation:** the key of each element of the array has to be the id fo the element itself. Example:

```
$ARRAY = array(
    1 => array( 'label' => "A" ),
    2 => array( 'label' => "B" ),
    3 => array( 'label' => "C" ),
    4 => array( 'label' => "D" ),
    5 => array( 'label' => "one", 'father' => '1' ),
    6 => array( 'label' => "two", 'father' => '1' ),
    7 => array( 'label' => "three", 'father' => '1' ),
    8 => array( 'label' => "node 1", 'father' => '2' ),
    9 => array( 'label' => "node 2", 'father' => '2' ),
    10 => array( 'label' => "node 3", 'father' => '2' ),
    11 => array( 'label' => "I", 'father' => '9' ),
    12 => array( 'label' => "II", 'father' => '9' ),
    13 => array( 'label' => "III", 'father' => '9' ),
    14 => array( 'label' => "IV", 'father' => '9' ),
    15 => array( 'label' => "V", 'father' => '9' ),
);
```

**Usage:** the function need $a (the array), $parent_key (the name of the column where the id of the father is saved), $children_key (the name of the column where the children will be move). It returns nothing (the array is changed by reference). Example:

```
treeze( $ARRAY, 'father', 'children' );
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $ARRAY );
```

Comment: Good way, faster than recurrence!  Needs a little fix, "Notice: Undefined index: father"

Comment: @PeterKrauss I've fixed the notice (and also improve a little bit the formatting)

Answer (score 3):

```
//if order by parentid, id
$arr = array(
    array('id'=>100, 'parentid'=>0, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>101, 'parentid'=>100, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>102, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
    array('id'=>103, 'parentid'=>101, 'name'=>'a'),
);

$arr_tree = array();
$arr_tmp = array();

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $parentid = $item['parentid'];
    $id = $item['id'];

    if ($parentid  == 0)
    {
        $arr_tree[$id] = $item;
        $arr_tmp[$id] = &$arr_tree[$id];
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!empty($arr_tmp[$parentid])) 
        {
            $arr_tmp[$parentid]['children'][$id] = $item;
            $arr_tmp[$id] = &$arr_tmp[$parentid]['children'][$id];
        }
    }
}

unset($arr_tmp);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr_tree); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with a recursive function that first finds all the bottom values of the list, adding them to a new array. Then for each new id, you use the same function on that id, taking the returned array and stuffing it in that item's new children array. Finally, you return your new array.

I won't do all the work for you, but the function's parameters will look something like:

function recursiveChildren($items_array, $parent_id = 0)

Essentially, it'll find all the ones with parent of 0, then for each of those it'll find all the ones with that id as the parent, and for each of those.. so on.

The end result should be what you are looking for.

Comment: The problem with this algorithm is that it is likely O(n^2). Consider an array where every element is the parent of the next. This algorithm would scan the array n times, resulting in n(n+1)/2 operations.

Comment: So remove the items from the old array as you find them before passing it along. My intention here was just to get a sketch of a function that will do the job. Not do the job fast. That's for optimization later on. This is the web. Caching is a better place to expend these kinds of mental energies.

Comment: My calculation of n(n+1)/2 operations accounted for the fact that the array is shrinking after every scan. The OP stated that his data structure was "way bigger"; I feel it is implied that O(n^2) is too expensive.

Comment: i was doing it like this until my tree where becomming to big that is way i asked for an efficient way it to mo about 1 second to create the tree and had to load several of them so this solution is to slow. i posted my solution this ony will do it in 5ms

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason this three pass method wouldn't work?  I didn't do any tests to compare speed to some of the recursive solutions, but it seemed more straight forward.  If your initial array is already associative with the IDs being the key, then you can skip the first `foreach()`.

```
function array_tree(&$array) {
    $tree = array();

    // Create an associative array with each key being the ID of the item
    foreach($array as $k => &$v) {
      $tree[$v['id']] = &$v;
    }

    // Loop over the array and add each child to their parent
    foreach($tree as $k => &$v) {
        if(!$v['parent']) {
          continue;
        }
        $tree[$v['parent']]['children'][] = &$v;
    }

    // Loop over the array again and remove any items that don't have a parent of 0;
    foreach($tree as $k => &$v) {
      if(!$v['parent']) {
        continue;
      }
      unset($tree[$k]);
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: personally, I'd make `$array` immutable and just add parentless items to a new array then return that array.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version:

```
function build_tree(&$items, $parentId = null) {
    $treeItems = [];
    foreach ($items as $idx => $item) {
        if((empty($parentId) && empty($item['parent_id'])) || (!empty($item['parent_id']) && !empty($parentId) && $item['parent_id'] == $parentId)) {
            $items[$idx]['children'] = build_tree($items, $items[$idx]['id']);
            $treeItems []= $items[$idx];
        }
    }

    return $treeItems;
}
build_tree($array);
```