# Get Magento Categories with Especific Sort of Admin Panel

Tags: php, magento

I wrote the code below to put together a customized menu of categories. Everything works fine, but would like the order of the categories were the same order as defined in the administrator panel where there drap and drop functionality.

```
<?php
    $subCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(76)->getChildren();
    $dispositosCatIds = explode(',',$subCats);
?>
<ul class="menu">
<?php $controleNum = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($dispositosCatIds as $dispositoCatId): ?>
<?php $aparelhoCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($dispositoCatId); ?>
<?php if($aparelhoCat->getIsActive()): ?>
    <li class="<?php print $controleNum ? '' : 'submenu first'; ?>"><a class="drop" href="<?php echo $aparelhoCat->getUrl(); ?>"> <span><?php echo $aparelhoCat->getName(); ?></span></a> <!--Begin 6 column Item  -->
    <div class="dropdown_6columns">
    <div class="inner"><span class="title"><?php echo $aparelhoCat->getName(); ?></span>
    <div class="col_2">
    <div class="col_2 firstcolumn"><img src="<?php echo $aparelhoCat->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $aparelhoCat->getName(); ?>" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <?php echo $aparelhoCat->getDescription(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col_2 categorias-super"><span class="title_col">Produtos para <?php echo $aparelhoCat->getName(); ?></span> 
    <?php $subSubCats = $aparelhoCat->getChildrenCategories();?>

    <?php if (count($subSubCats) > 0): ?>
        <?php //$controleNumLI = 0; ?>
        <ul style="list-style: none; float: none !important;">
        <?php foreach($subSubCats as $_subcategory): //Rodando entre as categorias de Um dispositivo ?>
            <?php if($_subcategory->getIsActive()): ?>
                <li class="level1 <?php //print $controleNumLI ? '' : 'first'; ?>"> <a href="<?php echo $_subcategory->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory->getName(); ?></a></li>
                <?php //$controleNumLI += 1; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <?php $controleNum += 1; ?>
<?php endif; ?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I tried to use other modes ([based here](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html#sec-methods)) can do this, but I could not. The problem that the function returns `getChildren()` is a string with IDs in ascending order.

Some Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
$dispositovosCategoryId = 76;
$dispositovosCategoryIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq'=>$dispositovosCategoryId))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',array('eq'=>true))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('level')
    ->setOrder('position','ASC')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name','url','image')
    ->load();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to display category in a dropdown box in the order of the admin... the key is  setOrder('path','ASC')

```
    $categories = array();

    $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',array('eq'=>true))
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('level')
                            ->setOrder('path','ASC')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')->load();




    foreach($_categories as $cat){
        $level = $cat->getLevel() - 1;
        $pad = str_repeat("----", ($level > 0) ? $level : 0);

        $categories[] = array('value' => $cat->getEntityId(), 'label' => $pad . ' ' . $cat->getName());
    }

    print_r($categories);
```

You could do something like this: [create array tree from array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196157/create-array-tree-from-array-list)

Comment: Thanks man. But your code only returns the categories in order admin of top level categories. I'll try to change it and any success I will comment here. If you have any suggestions, I'd be grateful.