# Create a tree array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have an array:

```
$data_array = array(
        array('id'=> 1 , 'parent_id' => 1 , 'name'=>'Air Vehicles' ),
        array('id'=> 2 , 'parent_id' => 2 , 'name'=>'Land Vehicles' ),
        array('id'=> 3 , 'parent_id' => 3 , 'name'=>'Water Vehicles' ),
        array('id'=> 4 , 'parent_id' => 2 , 'name'=>'Bikes' ),
        array('id'=> 5 , 'parent_id' => 2 , 'name'=>'Cars' ),
        array('id'=> 6 , 'parent_id' => 1 , 'name'=>'Aero Planes'),
        array('id'=> 7 , 'parent_id' => 1 , 'name'=>'Helicopter'),
        array('id'=> 8 , 'parent_id' => 3 , 'name'=>'Ships'),
        array('id'=> 9 , 'parent_id' => 1 , 'name'=>'Hoverboard'),
        array('id'=> 10 , 'parent_id' => 2 , 'name'=>'Hoverboard'),
        array('id'=> 11 , 'parent_id' => 4 , 'name'=>'R1 Kawasaki'),
        array('id'=> 12 , 'parent_id' => 4 , 'name'=>'Suzuki Hayabusa'),
        );
```

I want to create a tree array from above array:

```
Air Vechiles
-Aero Planes
-Helicopter
-HoverBoard
Land Vechiles
-Bikes
--R1 Kawasaki
--Suzuki Hayabusa
-Cars
Water Vehicles
-Ships
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts? If you didn't give it a try simply use `foreach`

Comment: SO is not a forum where people can write code for something you want to achieve. Instead saying 'I want to' you should let everyone know what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far and what is the problem you are facing, so that users can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your desired solution.

```
class CategoryTree{

public $padding_array;  

public function __construct(){
    $this->padding_array = array();
}

public function getTreeArray($data_array){
    foreach($data_array as $i=>$data){
        if($data['id'] == $data['parent']) $data_array[$i]['parent'] = 0;
    }
    return $this->getCategoryTreeArray($data_array);
}

public function getCategoryTreeArray($elements, $parent_id = 0){
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent'] == $parent_id) {
            $children = $this->getCategoryTreeArray($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}

public function getCatgoryPadingArray($tree_array, array &$padding_array, $depth=0){
    foreach ($tree_array as $id => $data_array) {
            $padding_array[$id] = str_repeat('-', $depth).$data_array['name'];
            if(is_array($data_array) && array_key_exists('children', $data_array)){
                $this->getCatgoryPadingArray($data_array['children'], $padding_array , $depth+1);
            }
    }
}}
```

Using class:

```
$data_array  = array(); // your array data
$tree_object = new CategoryTree();
$category_tree_array = $tree_object->getTreeArray($data_array);
$tree_object->getCatgoryPadingArray($category_tree_array, $tree_object->padding_array);
$category_padding_array = $tree_object->padding_array;
echo('<pre>');
print_r($category_padding_array);
echo('<pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with recursive calling of custom function or like this:

```
$data_array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Air Vehicles'),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Land Vehicles'),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Water Vehicles'),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Bikes'),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Cars'),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Aero Planes'),
    array('id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Helicopter'),
    array('id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Ships'),
    array('id' => 9, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Hoverboard'),
    array('id' => 10, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Hoverboard'),
    array('id' => 11, 'parent_id' => 4, 'name' => 'R1 Kawasaki'),
    array('id' => 12, 'parent_id' => 4, 'name' => 'Suzuki Hayabusa'),
);
$tree = array();
foreach ($data_array as $k => &$val) {
    if ($val['parent_id'] == $val['id']) {
        if (empty($tree[$val['parent_id']])) {
            $tree[$val['parent_id']] = array();
        }
        $tree[$val['parent_id']] = array_merge($tree[$val['parent_id']], $val);
    } else {
        $tree[$val['parent_id']]['sub'][] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($tree);
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating a tree array use a Recursive function. This is working perfectly for me :-

```
foreach($data_array as $i=>$data)
{
    if($data['id'] == $data['parent_id']) $data_array[$i]['parent_id'] = 0;
}

function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) 
{
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) 
    {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) 
        {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children)  $element['children'] = $children;
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}

$tree = buildTree($data_array);

echo '<pre>', print_r($tree, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$new = array();
foreach ($data_array as $a){
$new[$data_array['parentid']][] = $a;
}
$tree = createTree($new, array($data_array[0]));
print_r($tree);

function createTree(&$list, $parent){
$tree = array();
foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
    if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
        $l['children'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['id']]);
    }
    $tree[] = $l;
} 
return $tree;
}
```

Comment: For more info,see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196157/create-array-tree-from-array-list?wb48617274=21E5EF87

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this example, you should be able to figure out that all you need to do is replace the array name and values to accommodate your requirements. Clearly your data is not numbers so you need to find out for yourself how you would deal with the vehicle names.

```
  $tmpArray = array(array("one",array(1,2,3)),array("two",array(4,5,6)),array("three",array(7,8,9)));
```

And use print to check the structure

```
  print_r($tmpArray);
```