# Array grouping php into sub array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    array('menu' => 'Menu Parent 1', 'link' => '#'),
    array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 1', 'link' => '/submenu1'),
    array('menu' => 'Menu Parent 2', 'link' => '#'),
    array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 2.1', 'link' => '/submenu21'),
    array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 2.2', 'link' => '/submenu22'));
```

How can I turn it into the following array?

```
$array = array(
    array('menu' => 'Menu Parent 1', 'link' => '#',
          'submenu' => array(array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 1', 'link' => '/submenu1'))
    ),
    array('menu' => 'Menu Parent 2', 'link' => '#',
        'submenu' => array(array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 2.1', 'link' => '/submenu21'),
                           array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 2.2', 'link' => '/submenu22'))
    )
);
```

Comment: try to store your menus in the form of `id` and `parent id`.

Comment: [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is a good place to start understanding how PHP arrays work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) using a custom aggregate function and a new `array()` as initial value.

Or iterate over the list looking for guess the parents from the menu text: in your case may be complicated because the parent wire is not explicit as element attribute.

Similar question: [create array tree from array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196157/create-array-tree-from-array-list)

Answer (score 0):

Really don't know what exactly you want to do, but may be following code will help you to clarify your doubt.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('menu' => 'Menu Parent 1', 'link' => '#'),
    array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 1', 'link' => '/submenu1'),
    array('menu' => 'Menu Parent 2', 'link' => '#'),
    array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 2.1', 'link' => '/submenu21'),
    array('menu' => 'Sub Menu Parent 2.2', 'link' => '/submenu22')
);

$updatedData[0] = $data[0];
$updatedData[0]['submenu'] = array($data[1]);

$updatedData[1] = $data[2];
$updatedData[1]['submenu'] = array($data[3],$data[4]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($updatedData);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: @dario thanks for suggestions. i have any solution from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840319/build-a-tree-from-a-flat-array-in-php