# how to make php array tree?

Tags: php

There is the following array.

```
  $arrTmp = array();
  $arrTmp = array(
  array('id' => 206,
  'BoardName' => 'Schedule',
  'pid' => 196),

  array('id' => 145,
  'BoardName' => 'testboard3',
  'pid' => 196),

  array('id' => '197',
  'BoardName' => 'testboard',
  'pid' => 196),     
 
  array('id' => '198',
  'BoardName' => 'hawi',
  'pid' => 197),
 
  array('id' => '199',
  'BoardName' => 'hawi2',
  'pid' => 197)    
     
);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [BoardName] => Schedule
            [pid] => 196
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 145
            [BoardName] => testboard3
            [pid] => 196
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 197
            [BoardName] => testboard
            [pid] => 196
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 198
            [BoardName] => hawi
            [pid] => 197
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 199
            [BoardName] => hawi2
            [pid] => 197
        )     
  );
```

"Pid" is the parent of "id".
An array with "pid" 197 enters a sub-category of an array with id "197".

If there is no array of id values as pid, it is displayed like an array of 206 or 145 id. 206 or 145 is an example and does not necessarily have to match that value.

Examples of pid are "197" or "196", and there are many types of pid and id in the DB.

I want to make this Array as follows.

```
    $arrTmp2 = array(
    array('id' => 206,
    'title' => 'Schedule',
    'pid' => 196),
    
    array('id' => '197',
    'title' => 'testboard',
    'pid' => 196,
          'sub' => array(
              
            'hawi' => array
              (
               'title' => 'hawi',
              'id' => 198       
                ),
            'hawi2' => array
              (
               'title' => 'hawi2',
              'id' => 199       
                )
             
        )
    )
);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [title] => Schedule
            [pid] => 196
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 197
            [title] => testboard
            [pid] => 196
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [hawi] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => hawi
                            [id] => 198
                        )

                    [hawi2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => hawi2
                            [id] => 199
                        )

                )

        )
```

What should I do?
I ask for help.

```
foreach ($arrTmp as $key => $value) {


        
}
```

Comment: That is not really much of an attempt at solving this yourself!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe looks like a [tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)). You might find [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196157/create-array-tree-from-array-list) the implementation you need.

Comment: What you write is really just a comment,